# How to setup local Ubuntu server that provides security updates to ubuntu desktop systems?

Tags: server, updates, apt-mirror

I want to setup local Ubuntu server that download and provide security updates from internet as per requirement of Ubuntu desktop systems connected in local area network. How can I setup such server ?

Comment: I don't know the answer as such, but suggest you search askubuntu.com for how to create a 'local' or 'private' repository - your desktop clients would then connect to the repository to fetch their updates. See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline/Repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Ubuntu Server with [landscape](https://landscape.canonical.com/), which is a control panel to deploy updates and install packages for remote Ubuntu systems.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is to use **`apt-mirror`** to create a **local mirror** of another repository, which can then be used by other machines on your network.

Outdated but probably still useful instructions to do this can be found [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/local_debian_ubuntu_mirror).

Edit: Slightly more up-to-date tutorial is found [here](http://www.matrix44.net/cms/notes/gnulinux/create-a-local-ubuntu-mirror)